# R: Applying PortfolioAnalytics package (Return.portfolio, var.portfolio, SharpeRatio) by group

Tags: r, time-series, finance, portfolio, r-portfolioanalytics

I have a dataframe `p1` which consists of a time series of monthly stock returns, roughly 500 stocks for each month. I am trying to calculate the portfolio return, the portfolio variance and the Sharpe ratio for **each month**. For that I would like to use the `PortfolioAnalytics` package, applying Return.portfolio(), var.portfolio() and SharpeRatio() respectively.

My desired output would be a new dataframe (`p1pofo`) which consists of four columns (`"monthyear"`, `"PofoRet"`, `"PofoVar"`, `"PofoSharpe"`) and has one row for each value of `"monthyear"`.

In order to do that I tried to split the dataframe and then apply the respective function, exemplarily shown for Return.portfolio():

```
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(dplyr)
p1pofo <- p1 %>%
  split(list(p1$monthyear)) %>%
  map_df(~ mutate(., PofoRet=Return.portfolio(p1$MonthlyReturnT1, p1$EWweights)))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in try.xts(x, error = "'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible") : 
  'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible
```

Any help regarding flaws with my code or alternative ways to solve my task would be greatly appreciated.

*Reproducible data sample:*

```
p1 <- structure(list(PERMNO = c(10074, 10085, 10242, 10296, 10304, 
10376, 10074, 10242, 10376, 10446), date = structure(c(9129, 
9129, 9129, 9127, 9129, 9129, 9161, 9161, 9161, 9161), class = "Date"), 
    monthyear = c(199412, 199412, 199412, 199412, 199412, 
    199412, 199501, 199501, 199501, 199501), MonthlyReturnT1 = c(0.0638297872340425, 
    0.00714285714285712, 0.115384615384615, -0.0404040404040404, 
    -0.0379746835443038, 0.0510204081632653, 0.0208333333333333, 
    -0.0333333333333333, -0.00970873786407767, 0.0204081632653061
    ), EWweights = c(0.0040650406504065, 0.0040650406504065, 
    0.0040650406504065, 0.0040650406504065, 0.0040650406504065, 
    0.0040650406504065, 0.00395256916996047, 0.00395256916996047, 
    0.00395256916996047, 0.00395256916996047)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Look into apply.Rolling() in PerformanceAnalytics and see if that helps. You shouldn't need to use dplyr for what you want to do.

Comment: @JaredMarks: Thanks for your comment. I have to admit that I am not sure how apply.Rolling() should help me since I am not looking for a rolling window. Could you give me an example how you would solve my problem with the data sample?

Comment: After looking at your dataset i think you have a data cleaning/wrangling issue. You shouldn't worry about running any performance statistics until you get the data in a usable tabular format. What you really need is for each column to be a single stock return series and for your date to be the index. Then create a similar dataframe of the asset weights through time. That way you can make your dataframe an xts object and then Return.portfolio (and all other functions that require xts) will just work.